# Los prefijos CSS no aparecen al compilar con gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: css3, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Estoy utilizando `gulp-ruby-sass` en lugar de `gulp-sass` para la pre-compilación del código en scss de mi proyecto.
Resulta que aún teniendo prefijos en mi archivo `.scss` y siguiendo [la forma en que se declaran los mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

**como por ejemplo:**

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}
```

**Debería producir en el CSS algo como:**

```
.box {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**Pero solo obtengo:**

```
.box {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Sin los prefijos.

¿A alguien más le ocurre? ¿Será que simplemente `gulp-ruby-sass` no compila con los prefijos?

**De ésta manera tengo las tasks de gulp:**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require("gulp-ruby-sass");
// Requires browser-sync package for automatic browser refresh
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task("serve", ["sass"], function(){

  browserSync.init({
    server: "./src"
  });
  /**
  * Listens changes for all .scss files
  */
  gulp.watch("src/scss/*.scss", ["sass"]);
  /**
  * Listens changes for all .html files
  */
  gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("src/en/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

/**
 * Compile with gulp-ruby-sass
 */

gulp.task("sass", function () {
  return sass("src/scss/style.scss")
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    // Writes converted css to dest url
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: "src/*.css"}))
});
```

Comment: ¿En dónde viste los estilos resultantes, era el `src/css/styles.css`? En el navegador únicamente te debe aparecer el estilo correcto, en la mayoría de los navegadores debería ser solo `border-radius` que ya es un estándar.

Comment: Lo vi en el archivo generado, es decir: `src/css/style.css`

Comment: Que extraño, ejecuté el task `gulp sass` y si me muestra bien los resultados: https://jsfiddle.net/learnercys/ptuo75a9/ . El `css` resultante lo puse en un comentario del `scss` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acabo de correr la task `gulp-sass`, no `gulp-serve` como lo venía haciendo y pude ver en el error log que había un conflicto con la gema `sass` *(error que no me salía en el log cuando corría `gulp-serve`, el cuál también utilizaba la task de `sass`)*

Raro porque yo había instalado la gema desde el Gemfile anteriormente, así que volví a hacer un `bundle install` y volví a correr `gulp-sass`. Finalizó sin errores.

**Al revisar, ya salen los prefijos.**

Intenté con `gulp-serve` y ya funciona correctamente todo el proceso.

Si a alguien más le pasa, **asegúrense de tener correctamente instalada la gema `sass` en su proyecto**

Comment: Si ya encontraste la solución marca tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Me sale que debo esperar 2 días para hacerlo...